# How to use sails with cluster (to use more cores)?

Tags: node.js, cluster-computing, sails.js

I am trying to launch sails.js application with `cluster` library to allow it so spawn more processes to use all cores of my machine but somehow the method used with express fails here.

```
var cluster = require('cluster'),
    numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

// create the server 
if (cluster.isMaster) {
  for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }
  cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
    console.log('worker %d died (%s). restarting...', worker.process.pid, signal || code);
    cluster.fork();
  });
} else {
  // Start sails and pass it command line arguments
  require('sails').lift(require('optimist').argv);
  console.log("Sails forked");
}
```

After that I just normally run it via :

```
$ sails lift
```

but I get the same results when I run apache bench for this performance testing. Any help ? Am I missing something ?

**EDIT**

Even when I put `console.log` in `cluster.fork` if part then I do not get the output.

Comment: Is that a direct copy/paste of your code?  Where do you initialize `numCPUs`?  Have you confirmed that you are actually spinning up a worker for each CPU?

Comment: @Jason I have forgotten about that but yes, I initialize `numCPUs` just like in the code ( I have edited that ) and yet I get no output confirmation that I Sails have forked, just normal output like in standard Sails app.

Comment: You get no `Sales forked` message? What happens if you put a `console.log()` call in the master `numCPUs` loop?

Comment: @Jason I have updated my answer. There is no output on `console.log()` in `numCPUs` loop.

Comment: Moving to an answer to give more space to try some debugging...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Finally I have used [pm2 module](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) for this as mentioned in one of `sails` issues https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/170

One should first install it:

```
$ npm install -g pm2
```

and then run the script:

```
$ pm2 start app.js -i max
```

then you can monitor it with:

```
$ pm2 monit
```

[image]

or list the processess:

```
$ pm2 l
```

[image]

Comment: This is not working, as all sails instances will try to start on the same port. Any ideas on how to make it work on different ports dynamically?

Comment: Is the code in question (cluster) used with pm2, or is the code removed and pm2 does all that automatically?

Comment: If anyone stumbles here later, it seems like pm2 does this for you, so you don't need to add any cluster code to your original code. The -i option is what will setup the clusters. [https://keymetrics.io/2015/03/26/pm2-clustering-made-easy/](https://keymetrics.io/2015/03/26/pm2-clustering-made-easy/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see what your output is (much simplified code just for debugging):

```
var cluster = require('cluster'),
    numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;
console.log('global '+numCPUs);

// create the server 
if (cluster.isMaster) {
    console.log('master '+numCPUs);
    for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
        console.log('this is for CPU '+i);
        cluster.fork();
        console.log('just for giggles '+i);
    }
}
else {
    console.log('This is a worker!');
}
```

... presumably you should get the output from all of those calls.  If everything is as expected, start adding your code back in bit by bit, see if it breaks and where, or if it starts working.

If you miss some output or something is unexpected, and you still don't know what to do next, post your results here.

Here's an example of expected output, from my dev server:

```
global 8
master 8
this is for CPU 0
just for giggles 0
this is for CPU 1
just for giggles 1
this is for CPU 2
just for giggles 2
this is for CPU 3
just for giggles 3
this is for CPU 4
just for giggles 4
this is for CPU 5
just for giggles 5
this is for CPU 6
just for giggles 6
this is for CPU 7
just for giggles 7
global 8
This is a worker!
global 8
This is a worker!
global 8
This is a worker!
global 8
global 8
This is a worker!
This is a worker!
global 8
This is a worker!
global 8
This is a worker!
global 8
This is a worker!
```

... which demonstrates a couple interesting things, actually, if you're not very familiar with cluster's API or just want to see it in action, specifically that `cluster.fork()` is an asynchronous call (i.e. it *will not* execute until the next loop, hence why you don't start seeing the workers announce themselves until after they've all been forked), but that child processes, once spawned, will execute in parallel (hence the doubling up of `global 8` and `This is a worker!` messages in the middle).